# Why can't I up-vote a locked question?

Tags: discussion, upvotes, locked-posts, historical-lock

Am I not supposed to up-vote a locked question? Why?

I can understand that high amount of off-topic comments can be a big mess. But why is up-voting restricted?

Comment: **All** actions are locked. No voting, no commenting, no answering, no deleting. It's is there for historical significance *only*. Why should upvoting be an exception here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters how will you define historical significance in case of questions?

Comment: If it is off-topic today but has been (very) popular in the past, usually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, I have seen a question locked just because it has high amount of off-topic comments generated.

Comment: @VVK - in that case it might be locked for a short time only while the dispute is cleared up. Do you have an example?

Comment: @ChrisF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @VVK: That is a special case. That post attracts loads of unnecessary noise because of Bobince's famous answer. It's like everyone trying to graffiti John Lennon's house.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I can understand. But for this special case "why is up-voting restricted ?"

Comment: @VVK: Because a lock is not that granular. Besides, don't you think the upvotes on that post are more due to overexposure than to genuine 'this post helped me' votes?

Comment: Related feature request: [Can we get a comments only lock?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171223/can-we-get-a-comments-only-lock)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree with VVK , e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java was locked for being a wiki-question, but is on-topic. Upvote still makes sense for the question.

Comment: @CiroSantilli so what point is there to vote on that post? No one gets rep for the votes, there is just the one answer so there is no comparative scores required. Extra votes on the question won't make it more visible or signal it is 'better' than other posts. I don't really see a problem here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "Extra votes on the question won't make it more visible or signal it is 'better' than other posts." Why? How is it different from other questions where that is the main purpose of upvoting?

Comment: @CiroSantilli: so how is a question with 731 votes better than one with 730? By that time the signal lost all meaning.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's all about scale. It would be meaningful to compare an answer with score 1000 with *another one* with score 3000. And those answers only get differentiated through deltas of 1 at a time :) Though I agree it's not super serious for those highly upvoted ones.

Comment: @CiroSantilli: within a question we are constantly showing answers as ranked because within that context the votes have meaning. That's not the case between answers from different questions; by that time a lot of the context (how popular the question is, the age of the question, etc.) is lost. Between questions I don't consider there to be much context to compare score *at all*. Past the first 20 or so votes on questions votes lose almost all meaning.

Comment: Locking a topic and its related answers, so that it can't be commented or even voted, is a slap in the face to community users.  It's basically saying, "End of discussion. Period. It doesn't really matter if someone has a new thought to add. We want to become old and irrelevant."

Answer (score 3):

A locked question is locked because it has historical significance and would be closed if asked today.

It also may be locked if it attracts a lot of attention and off-topic comments. There's no use in having new answers pop up on an old question each month, pushing it back to the top of the front page.

Either way, if you're upvoting a locked question, you're probably misusing voting.

From [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote):

> [Voting] on questions and answers is the primary mechanism through which the community governs the site on a day to day basis.

That is, if a question asked three years ago has 400 upvotes, it doesn't do you much good to add another one, particularly if it is locked.

Voting is meant to govern the site on a **day-to-day** basis.

Of course, there will be those who disagree because it is easy to coast on the reputation gained from old questions and answers that resolve common issues and come up often in Google searches.

I agree that some old questions and answers are just so well-phrased or interesting that they deserve an upvote despite their age, but most really don't

The hover text says:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear.

That is of course timeless, but it neglects the purpose of voting in the first place.

It's locked for a reason, though: if you're going to *lock* something, you might as well lock the whole thing. There's no use in locking just the comments and allowing voting to continue.

Comment: Many things are still needed after several years, especially if you work on a 'legacy' system -- see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score -7):

I was just about to ask this question myself.   My own take on this is that we should be able to vote on any question.  Some topics do not get less important with age, and the fact that it is found presumably indicates that it is useful/relevant/interesting to our programming lives.

Furthermore, it seems unfair to the original poster, who could otherwise gain reputation (and possibly privileges, badges, etc.) from the up votes.

Comment: I can respect that you have an opinion on this, but this doesn't actually *answer* the question.

Comment: Do you want me to ask a new question:  "Should we be able to vote on locked posts" -- then, my 'answer' WOULD be an answer!  LOL

Comment: Well, no...your new question would likely and easily be closed as a dupe of this one, which explains why you *can't*.

Comment: This would have been better written as a comment. The relevance of the question is, well, irrelevant to whether it gets locked. Historical locks are put on questions which are otherwise off-topic. I assure you, almost all historically locked posts have plenty of reputation rewarded.

Comment: I actually did post this as a question -- this also seems unfair, if my answer doesn't answer the original question, but it DOES answer my new question, CLEARLY the new question is not a duplicate of the old question....

Comment: So, you have every opportunity to express your opinion here, or on the internet at large. In this case, the suggestion is to write a comment, since the opinion doesn't answer the question. Asking a new question just to express an opinion is not the right way to go either. If you wanted to write a new question as a feature request to allow for voting on historically locked questions, you would need to present cogent reasons for SO to change the way it works. More than "I want to vote on one" or "it's not fair". Risk/reward, pros/cons, that kind of thing.