# Why can't I upvote the regex reference question?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, locked-posts

I just recently became aware of the existence of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) and its [related meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate)).  "Oh, wow," I thought, "that looks like a useful question! Let me upvote it..."

> [image: "This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on."]

Oh, I guess not, then. :(

Apparently, the reason I can't do that is because the question has been locked:

> ### locked by Robert Harvey♦ Apr 8 '14 at 18:46
>
> This question's answer is a collaborative effort: if you see something that can be improved, just edit to improve it! *No additional answers can be added here*

This seems sensible... except that it also blocks voting and commenting on the question. It also doesn't look like anyone ever even *tried* to add a second answer (not that there ever was much of an opportunity, as the question was locked less than 6 hours after it was asked).

OK, so I *could* still upvote the *answer* to that question (which currently stands at 216 votes, versus the question's 52).  But it was the question that I originally came across in the search results, and I'd rather like to upvote it, in order to see it rank higher there.

**So, basically, what I'd like to ask is:**

1. Is there any way to achieve the stated intent of the lock (preventing additional answers) without also preventing voting?
2. Could some less intrusive mechanism, such as [protection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question), achieve the same goal sufficiently well?
3. Is restricting this question to have only one answer, and enforcing this by technical means, something we need or want in the first place?

Comment: Surely it has enough votes already.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Evidently not, since it took me this long to find it. In fact, I'm somewhat surprised that typing "what does this regex mean" into the *Close > Duplicate* tab only returns this question in the 27th(!) place, even though, AFAIK, that list is *supposed* to be at least partly influenced by voting. (FWIW, [this is the top result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371149/regex-what-does-mean) for that search. Not very useful, alas.)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20does%20this%20regex%20mean - First result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I up-vote a locked question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262107/why-cant-i-up-vote-a-locked-question)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Please integrate google into the close-duplicate dialogue :-)

Comment: @sphanley: That's surely related, but I don't think it's really a dupe. That question and its answer assume that the question "is locked because it has historical significance and would be closed if asked today", and then argue (more or less convincingly) that this also means it should not be voted on. However, that's *not* the reason given for locking *this* specific question.

Comment: @sphanley: In other words, if locking really is meant only for historical purposes, I'm asking whether we really should be (ab)using it for reference questions like this, given that it blocks voting as a side effect; OTOH, if locking is also meant to be used for reference questions, then the answers to the "dupe" you linked to are based on a false premise, and thus useless in this specific instance.

Comment: That's fair. It doesn't totally answer your question but here's another post which gives some insight on the difference between the types of locks and the reasons for them: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280534/3486353