# Why can't I upvote a locked question but can upvote its answers?

Tags: discussion, voting, locked-posts

I wanted to upvote a [classic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), but I've seen it's not possible.

I found a [related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262107/why-cant-i-up-vote-a-locked-question) (not exactly the same and still unanswered):

> A locked question is locked because **it has historical significance and would be closed if asked today**.
>
> It also may be locked if it attracts a lot of attention and off-topic comments. There's no use in having new answers pop up on an old question each month, pushing it back to the top of the front page.
>
> Either way, if you're upvoting a locked question, you're probably misusing voting.
>
> From [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote):
>
> > [Voting] on questions and answers is the primary mechanism through which the community governs the site on a day to day basis.
> >     That is, if a question asked three years ago has 400 upvotes, it doesn't do you much good to add another one, particularly if it is locked.
>
> **Voting is meant to govern the site on a day-to-day basis.**

If the purpose is to preserve the question, because it has some meaning, but is not actually on-topic, and we don't want to attract attention or pushing to active ones...

**...then why is it allowed to vote on the answers of locked questions?**

Comment: Flipping it around, why wouldn't you be able to vote on the question anymore - probably because it would only net downvotes eternally. I can guess that's why the question is protected, but the answers don't suffer the same problems. They're still content that are subject to being rated for the usual reasons.

Comment: I suspect the real reason to be a technicality. All locks functionally do the same thing - they prevent all actions on the post. That question was probably locked either to stop the flow of copy-cat answers or some sort of close-vote war over its scope. The inability to vote was not the intention, but merely an unfortunate side-effect of using a nuke to solve an ant problem.

Comment: I've seen an answer locked before on another site, separately from the question. (It was weird. The message still called it a question); I suppose technically the lock only applies to the post that is locked, not any related ones.

Comment: @jpaugh The [famous regex answer is locked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: FWIW, @Mysticial is correct. There's only one lock, we just change the post notice added to the post. The singular exception is the historical locks, but they are the lock plus other stuff (easy), not the lock minus stuff, which would be difficult. That said, it's often silly to prevent voting or comments on some locks (wiki locks, for example). I'm hoping we can revisit our locks sometime soon.